# Update iOS app from new project

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store-connect

I've an application on the Apple Store.

I restart the project of nothing and I would like to make an update of the existing project.

How to submit this code as new build on itunes connect?

How do I delete the existing application data from my users' devices?

Comment: Just make similar bundle identifier will do I suppose

Comment: _existing application data_. What type of data you are talking about? Is it coredata, sqlite, Userdefaults, etc?

Comment: @Poles The datas from assets folder and from application bundle folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same bundle identifier as in your previous project. If you still have access to this Xcode project, open it, select your project name in the upper left tree view, the select your project target on the right (not the project, but the target) and select "General" in the upper menu. You will see "Bundle identifier". Use the same and you are done.

If you do not have access to your old xcode project, download the app from the app store into iTunes. Right click the app inside iTunes and select "Reveal in Finder". Copy the .ipa file and rename it to .zip, then open the zip archive and have a look into the file "iTunesMetadata.plist", which contains a key named "softwareVersionBundleId". This is the bundle id you have to enter into your xcode project.

Comment: thanks, i've resolve this problem, you can consult my comment on @Arun post

Comment: What exactly do your mean with "delete existing data from my users devices"? Which data do you mean? As long as you are using the same bundle identifier, you should also be able to access the existing data as the old version of the app also did.

Comment: My application allows to download and read a proprietary file format. With this new version, we are using a new data type (new file extension). The code undergoes a lot of change and when updating via the App store, I want to delete the old files, become unusable and can be very heavy (up to 500mo per file). In summary, I would like this update to act as a clean new installation

Comment: The binary will be like a new one after update. The data a user downloaded and stored needs to be deleted manually by your application, maybe by setting a flag when the new version is started. If this flag does not exist, this must be the very first start of your new version of the app, and you will delete all user data manually. Apple will not do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Upload with the previous apps Bundle identifier and new version, I think this is mostly enough to update your existing application.

Comment: I could not use the same identifier because i'd written the code from an other computer. but is now OK since I export / import my developer license from my old mac. One problem less, I still have to know how to delete data from existing applications